# PropertyReference Exception in ManyToOne Mapping

Tags: java, spring, one-to-many, many-to-one

I am using `ManyToOne` annotation mapping in my **VerticalTask** class

```
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "vertical_type_id")
private VerticalType vertical;
```

I have **VerticalType** class also where I am mapping the `OneToMany` annotation since I want **vertical task** for each company

```
@OneToMany (mappedBy = "vertical", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
orphanRemoval = true) private List<VerticalTask> verticalTask;
```

I also have verticalTaskRepository

```
public interface VerticalTaskRepository extends CrudRepository<VerticalTask, Long>{

    List<VerticalTask> findByVertical_type_Id(Long aircraft_typeId);
}
```

I have a column **verticalName** in **VerticalType** class  therefore using that I want to get All vertical task associated with one **VerticalType** record

I have also mentioned a mapping in postgresql `(vertical_type_id) -> (id)`

But at runtime I am getting Exception::

> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 7;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'verticalTaskRepository': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No
>   property name found for type VerticalType! Traversed path:
>   VerticalTask.vertical.

Comment: I figured out the error when I have commented the task repository method then it worked actually I want to get it using id but still the same error

Comment: Problem is with `findByVertical_type_Id` method because it doesn't follow convection. You need to use camelCase instead of snake_case. By which field do you wanna fetch data from the database?

Comment: @KamilW. vertical_type_id is the column itself in vertical task...I want to fetch using vertical_type_id which is a foreign key in vertical task and related to vertical_type

Comment: @KamilW. I solved it.... actually I named `private VerticalType vertical;` like therefore the method should be `findByVertical_Id`

Comment: Please paste additionally how your primary key field in VerticalType looks like. And take a look at [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) table. First mistake which are you making is you using database columns name instead of field names in java classes to make suitable method name.